# How can I record dynamically changing HTML using Selenium or something?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape a webpage, but it periodically changes the content, by getting additional information periodically using WebSocket.

So I have to scrape a webpage every time when it changes its content. Or, if it's possible, I can record the webpage content.

Is there any opensource or program that I can achieve this? Can Selenium do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "record the webpage content"?

Comment: @Alexander Oh, I mean writing down or memorize all the changes of content on the webpage. Thanks for your interest in my question :)

Comment: @Alexander Better way to achieve this is to read the html content only when the content is updated. (maybe I can define an event for this? Now I just read the html content for every 0.01 sec and compare the previous content and current content to check whether it has been updated or not.)

Comment: Sure you can do that with many tools.

Comment: @Alexander I see! Could you give some hints?

Comment: Selenium will work fine.  you just need to query the page and check the elements that are prone to change, and compare them to previous requests to see if the element has been updated.

Comment: @Alexander The website has some delay; it loads contents for about 2 secs everytime I reload the page, and the data is sent through WebSocket, so querying won't help I think